# emacs23 buffer menu font (GTK)

Tags: emacs, fonts, gtk, customization, emacs23

I've recently upgraded to emacs23 (Ubuntu 10.04) and I've managed to get my faces (fonts) all sorted out with relevant .emacs options.

However the one font I can't seem to change is the one used to display the Buffer Menu (i.e. when you CTRL+left-click on a buffer, you get a pop-up menu that lists all open buffers).

The problem is that the font used to display this menu is proportional (not fixed-width) and it makes a big mess of the menu - nothing is lined up vertically, and I often use this to see which buffers hold files that are in common directories. The proportional font has the paths all over the place.

I believe Ubuntu's emacs23 was built with GTK rather than Lucid. Some things I've read seem to indicate that there's no way to set this font within Emacs - that is has to be done externally using GTK config - if this is true, how?

Otherwise, if it can't be done, how tricky is it to recompile emacs23 with Lucid rather than GTK support on Ubuntu? Can it be done easily with "apt-get source"?

Comment: According to the GNU Emacs manual, section 18.6 "Standard Faces": 
"""menu : This face determines the colors and font of Emacs's menus. See Menu Bars. This has no effect in Emacs built with GTK and in the MS-Windows/Mac ports; you need to use system-wide styles and options to change the appearance of GTK, Windows, or Mac menus."""

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: As an aside, `ibuffer` is great for grouping and filtering the buffers you have open. This is especially the case if you end up with a great many buffers open, as the pop-up menus will become less readable as the lists get bigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I have discovered the answer:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/GTK-resources.html

The idea is to create ~/.emacs.d/gtkrc and use the GTK config mechanism to set up alternative styles for emacs' GTK widgets.

```
$ cat ~/.emacs.d/gtkrc
style "menufont"
{
  font_name = "monospace 10"  # Pango font name
}
widget "*emacs-menuitem*" style "menufont"
```

Seems to work well.

Comment: @Exaos I don't think I have this problem with GTK3 at the moment, however if you do find a solution then please return and let us know.